# My question gets marked as off-topic, then after people answer, it gets put "on hold"

Tags: support, closed-questions

So long story short I had a thought about a question pertinent to the outlets and meter of my house. I searched Stack Exchange and figured that Electrical Engineering is probably my best bet.

So I went ahead and posted [my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/381934/is-it-possible-to-request-a-mapped-diagram-of-electricity-usage-from-your-provid#). Immediately I get accused of posting something as off-topic. There was a bit of back-n-forth with another user in the comments.

Then, 3 answers were submitted. And I marked the one that answered my question the best as accepted. Then, moments later the question gets marked as "on hold" as off-topic.

I am not sure what to do, as I feel like this is not right at all. And it's not fair towards the other members who spent time and answered my question.

I went to [their chatroom and asked](https://i.gyazo.com/7c939046997c25a5859294b6082001d2.png), but not getting anywhere. Is there anything I can do? Or should I just let it go?

Comment: So now you close this as off-topic too? Why? I received plenty of help from @Glorfindel  This site is extremely harsh towards new users, my lord.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand and voted to reopen. You don't have the required reputation to post on Electrical Engineering meta anyway.

Comment: @Glorfindel: FWIW, anyone can ask on any site meta about one of their own questions on main, no rep required.

Comment: ah, yeah, I keep forgetting that.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yeah, I don't feel comfortable to post there again anyway haha. I will probably do the sites-recommendation first. FWIW, I asked a question on stackoverflow regarding the crystal programming language, and everyone was like extremely cordial (like you here). But it feels like the electrical engineering one is like a totally different beast. That's just my experience. Although, to be fair, the answers I got in the EE sub were very helpful.  Then, this gets marked as off-topic, I'm really shocked lol

But I am appreciated that at least someone understands where I'm coming from =]

Comment: Well, your responses don't really help your case at all.  You were told very clearly that your question was off-topic, and why, and you decided to argue the point.  You then used the fact that someone answered as justification to keep the question open, which doesn't invalidate the fact that it was off-topic in the first place.  An answered question doesn't mean it's useful, nor should stay open.

Comment: @fbueckert It most certainly does. It shows it's relevant to the community and obviously not off-topic, if it's receiving answers. Please don't victim blame, thanks

Comment: A question being answered != on-topic.  Someone being able to answer the question != on-topic.  That's like saying I can ask how to cook a cake on EE.SE, and if someone answers, it's relevant and on-topic.  A question's answerability has absolutely zero relevance to on or off-topicness.  There's no victim blaming; just common sense.

Comment: @fbueckert Now you are distorting what I have said. I said it has received 3 answers, not just 1 answer. ("A question being answered != on-topic") -- And talking about how electrical outlets are connected to a meter, and if it's possible for an energy provider to generate a diagram (engineering part) 100% falls under electrical engineering.

Yes, you are victim blaming by saying statements like "don't really help your case at all." If you don't have anything nice to say,  please don't comment.

Comment: You're arguing with the wrong person; I don't use EE.  I'm just pointing out the flaws in your argument.  It doesn't matter how many answers a question gets; at Arqade, one of our more popular tags was identify-the-game.  They got tons of answers.  And they are still off-topic.  If you want to argue on-topicness, you know where to do it.  It's not here.

Comment: "You're arguing with the wrong person" Then don't start an argument with me.

btw, you have pointed out zero flaws with my argument.

Comment: Alright, you tell yourself that.  Now please go to Meta.EE if you want to continue arguing, because this isn't the place.

Comment: You were the one who initiated to argue me in the first place, lol.

Comment: ...aaaaaand this is why it's completely acceptable to downvote answers (good or not) on off topic questions. Saved for future reference.

Comment: @Won't What do you mean?

Comment: > posts off topic question > but it's got three answers so it's okay > currentmemereactionimage.jpg

Comment: @JohnMiller - In other words, Issuing a downvote to an answer, to a question that isn't on within scope of the site is justified.  of course you don't need any justification to issue any vote.

Comment: @Won't Huh? I'm saying if my topic I asked got relevant answers to my question, it shows it's not really off-topic. It shows that the community understood my question and other community members felt the need to answer it.  Especially when those answers were 100% relevant, which 2 of them were.

Comment: @Won't And my original post was not off-topic in my opinion. Electrical part was the outlets connecting to the meter, and the engineering part, was whether or not the energy provider could create this diagram from the meter. In fact, 2 people from their community answered my question fully and totally understood it. And to them, I greatly appreciate it! Sadly, I couldn't upvote them from the downvotes from their own community. "15 rep required"

Comment: @JohnMiller - Anyone can answer any question, even a spam qustion, doesn't make the spam question ontopic.  Just because your question recieved an answer, by users who would answer any question, does not mean your question was ontopic.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not true imo. Totally depends on the answer and if it's relevant to the question, and is on-topic.

Comment: @JohnMiller - The linked question is still on hold.  Questions that are not within the scope of a community should be closed.  If you disagree, then you should bring it up at meta.EE, although it's unlikely you will change anyone's minds using the arguments you are using.  Any question can be answered, not all questions with answers are within scope, thus those questions should be closed to prevent additional answers being submitted.

Comment: @Ramhound I am saying "if the answers were helpful". Which 2 of them were, they both understood my question, and supplied electrical engineering information in their answers. Which further proves my original question is relevant and not off-topic.

Comment: @JohnMiller - So flag the question so it can be reopened.  However, only one of those answers received an upvote, which I presume was from you.

Comment: @Ramhound Nah mate not from me, I can't upvote anything there lol. The downvotes I got from their community, stripped the ability for me to upvote answers. It says I need 15 reputation or something. It did let me mark it as accepted though

Comment: You are going to have to accept that the EE SE community has decided that question isn't actually on-topic.  I stand by my statement that an answer can be well received to a question that isn't on-topic.  Does not change the fact the question isn't on-topic.

Comment: @Ramhound Just because 5 or so members of their community says it's off-topic, doesn't necessarily mean it's *true*. Especially when 2 answers understood my question completely, and supplied relevant EE info in their answers. Which totally helped me a lot. It's not fair to those members who spent time to answer my question (that they thought wasn't off-topic), to not get reputation. That is not right.

Comment: @JohnMiller Those users should vote to reopen your question in that case

Comment: I've had this kind of circumstance happen to me with this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437178/what-is-a-word-for-a-restriction-imposed-by-a-persons-religion Though my question clearly pertains to the English language and was answered, what happens is that each site has certain arbitrary standards listed in their guidelines under the very small help button on the drop-down site tab. Sites don't allow just any question relevant to the site topic, they only allow specific kinds of questions of their arbitrary choosing within the scope of the larger topic in the guidelines.

Comment: @JohnJoe  That seems absolutely ridiculous. But yeah far more "on-topic" than mine for sure.  Only reason that I will continue to use this site is because of Glorfindel's cordiality in his response. Gives me a glimmer of hope there are still people left, that actually care. Instead of just downvoting or posting meme comments. Seems like to me compassion and sympathy are rare traits on this site, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @JohnMiller I agree that there is little to no place for arbitrary judgement in the learning of individuals. If someone thinks a question can be improved, instead of distracting it with downvoting, they should work with the person on equal grounds to suggest improvements and not abuse an arbitrary, and ultimately irrelevant power dynamic that was supposed to protect users from such circumstances. I've been an educator and I can see stackexchange rarely cares about members as it demonstrates a lack of sympathy and patience with circumstances such as yours, it seems purely about personal hubris.

Comment: @JohnJoe: "Off-topic" doesn't actually mean off-topic. It means *fits a particular set ofclose reasons that the community has decided on*. These are generally formulated in a way that is very far from arbitrary, although sometimes their use is questionable in particular cases. The [dubious labeling of "off-topic" close reasons has been brought up before](/questions/186024/can-we-rename-the-off-topic-close-reason-label-on-the-primary-screen), along with [a request to allow diversified custom reasons](/questions/210314/categories-other-than-off-topic-should-allow-custom-close-reasons).

Comment: @NathanTuggy The definitions of the topics do not state users can't ask questions about those topics. Therefore, the authoritarian imposition of which questions can be asked must be arbitrary, which your comment " 'Off-topic' doesn't actually mean off-topic." shows. If you're saying "doesn't actually..." then you've already admitted that SE has contradicted the accepted English definition of the topics in the rest of the world. However, that doesn't mean all of SE's arbitrary authoritarian impositions are bad, there are reasons to limit spam and toxicity, though sometimes at a cost of abuse.

Comment: @JohnJoe: They're not *arbitrary*, they're *mislabeled*. Those are two very different problems. I'm not saying "off-topic" is a good name for the concept. It isn't. What I am saying is that it is not some sort of dart-board slapdash affair. Rather, sincere efforts to produce a decent system ran into limited resources and differences of opinion about how best to go about it.

Comment: @JohnJoe: As far as the choice of custom close reasons, those are not to guard against spam and toxicity, which is easy enough. They are there to make sure questions get good answers that the site's users can vote on well so that the collection of Q&A is a useful resource for visitors. Types of questions that can be identified as posing various sorts of problems will, generally after considerable discussion on that site's meta, eventually be judged off-topic, meaning "doesn't work on this site". The philosophy of most reasons is generally consistent, but the details vary from site to site.

Comment: @JohnJoe: (For example, consider [the early discussion on proofreading questions on ELL Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/should-proofreading-questions-be-closed-as-offtopic). The philosophy is to make sure questions are useful to others. The details work out in specific ways for the site, and that's [changed over the years](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2547/lets-rewrite-the-proofreading-close-reason).)

Comment: @NathanTuggy What is considered "good" is arbitrary and no subject listed on SE is defined by SE's opinion of good in the English language, or any other official language in the world. Physics is not defined by your emotional opinion on what is good, neither is Earth Science nor any other science, they are areas of study. Arbitrary is not random, arbitrary is subject to personal whims without necessity for logical reasoning, which those rules are. SE members personally decided to impose those arbitrary restrictions at the expense of the the time and learning of thousands for other people.

Comment: @JohnJoe: Please refrain from emotional ranting and personal attacks, especially labeling as "personal whims" and "illogical" the thoughtful, detailed arguments and decisions of thousands of experienced users working together on hundreds of sites across the years.

Comment: @NathanTuggy If I see that I am emotionally ranting, then I will refrain from such. However, I have not seen that I have done such. What I have done is point out that the arbitrary restrictions imposed by SE are not consistent with what the rest of the world defines the subjects listed on SE to be. If 1000 experienced chefs say "cake is good," that is still an opinion, and it does not necessitate you force users to eat cake. Logical reasoning is not dependent on experience. Even if these alleged members are experienced, you are only using an arbitrary criteria for what constitutes experienced.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might simply be a conflict of opinions; one person found it interesting/on-topic enough to answer it; *five* people voted to close it as off-topic, deeming it a bad fit for the site. Note that five people (others, or even the close voters) can also *reopen* it if they disagree with the closure.

> I get accused of posting something as off-topic.

It might feel that way, but Stack Exchange is focused on *content*, not *users*. You are not accused in any way; it's your *question* that's under discussion. Stack Exchange sites need to have a specific *scope* to make sure the questions can be answered properly; generally speaking that means high-quality, objective answers by people who are knowledgeable about the subject.

> Is there anything I can do?

It's going to be hard to modify this question so that it will become on-topic for Electrical Engineering. But there are more Stack Exchange sites out there; on Meta we can help you with a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation). I'm not particularly sure about this question, but it might fit on [DIY Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Cool! Yeah, I was reading the wikipedia on EE and it said "Electrical engineering is a professional engineering discipline that generally deals with the study and application of electricity". And I figured the outlets and the meter is the electric part. And the energy company "possibly" generating a diagram from the meter data is the "engineering" part. That's kinda why I went back n forth with that user in the comments. Very cool about sites-recommendation, I should have probably used that. Thanks for your cordial response, I'm going to just let it go

Comment: Hey @Glorfindel, I am going to delete this question. They marked it as off-topic and it's continuing to get downvotes. I appreciate your cordial response, but this site is way too harsh towards new users, I don't really feel comfortable continuing to use a site with a community like this. With that said however, I do appreciate your response greatly =] Thanks again

Comment: @JohnMiller - You cannot delete this question.  You have already received an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that out after I posted :P